# Is Roger Federer's 65 consecutive Grand Slams a record?

Tags: tennis, records, grand-slam

In 2016, Roger Federer missed a Grand Slam for the first time in his career, the [French Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_French_Open). This was the first Grand Slam he had not competed in since the since [2000 Australian Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_Australian_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles), i.e. 65 straight Grand Slams.

Is this a record? If it is, then what is the next highest number of consecutive slams played without a withdrawal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Roger Federer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Federer#Career_statistics)'s 65 consecutive Grand Slam tournaments (2001 US Open - 2016 Australian Open) was indeed a record at the time of posting this question. Since then he was surpassed by [Feliciano López](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feliciano_L%C3%B3pez#Performance_timelines) with 79 (2002 French Open - 2022 Australian Open), [Fernando Verdasco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_Verdasco#Career_statistics) with 67 (2003 Wimbledon - 2020 Australian Open) and [Andreas Seppi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andreas_Seppi#Performance_timelines) with 66 (2005 Wimbledon - 2022 Australian Open).

You should be able to find a list which is up to date in the Wikipedia article linked below.

**Sources:**

- [List of Grand Slam related tennis records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Grand_Slam_related_tennis_records#Participation) at Wikipedia (link to a [revision from 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_Grand_Slam_related_tennis_records&oldid=747362521#Singles_participation_(all_time)) and a [revision from 2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_Grand_Slam%E2%80%93related_tennis_records&oldid=1088357631#Participation))
- [List of career achievements by Roger Federer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_career_achievements_by_Roger_Federer#Open_Era_records_-_Grand_Slams) at Wikipedia (link to a [revision from 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_career_achievements_by_Roger_Federer&oldid=750436859#Open_Era_records_-_Grand_Slams))
- [Djokovic Set To Defend Wimbledon Title](http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/news/djokovic-scouting-report-wimbledon-2016) - June 2016 ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/news/djokovic-scouting-report-wimbledon-2016))
- [Federer, Big Four Looking To Reach New Heights At Wimbledon](http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/news/wimbledon-2015-preview-sharko-1) - June 2015 ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/news/wimbledon-2015-preview-sharko-1))
- [Wimbledon diary: Feliciano López reveals secret of playing long game](https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2018/jul/04/feliciano-lopez-secret-wimbledon-diary) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20180917144248/https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2018/jul/04/feliciano-lopez-secret-wimbledon-diary))
- [Lopez Falls In Roland Garros Qualifying As Grand Slam Streak Ends](https://www.atptour.com/en/news/roland-garros-2022-tuesday-qualifying) - May 2022 ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20220522140640/https://www.atptour.com/en/news/roland-garros-2022-tuesday-qualifying))